# Length of upstream and downstream of tss important for gene regulation o

Tags: gene-regulation

I want to find SNPs in the upstream and downstream regions of transcription start sites of some 42 genes implicated in a disease (on which I am working).

Are there any suggestions on what length should be covered both upstream and downstream? Is there a database which can give the transcription factor binding region of both upstream and downstream regions as a batch query? Or a paper to which I can refer for the search length for looking for SNPs?